# Travis builds fail with "apt-get install failed"

Tags: travis-ci

My travis builds fail with the following error from time to time, any ideas on how I can fix this?

> The command "sudo -E apt-get -yq --no-install-suggests
>   --no-install-recommends $(travis_apt_get_options) install mysql-server mysql-client" failed and exited with 100 during.

travis.yaml

```
language: python
python:
- '2.7'
env:
  global:
  - CACHE_PATH=${HOME}/.cache
  - CLOUD_SDK_PATH=${CACHE_PATH}/google-cloud-sdk
  - GAE_SDK_PATH=${CLOUD_SDK_PATH}/platform/google_appengine

services:
  - mysql

addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - mysql-5.7-trusty
    packages:
      - mysql-server
      - mysql-client

dist: trusty
sudo: required
```

Output:

```
0.71s$ sudo -E apt-get -yq --no-install-suggests --no-install-recommends $(travis_apt_get_options) install mysql-server mysql-client
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libterm-readkey-perl
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libmecab2 libmysqlclient-dev libmysqlclient20 mysql-common
  mysql-community-client mysql-community-server
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mysql-client-5.6 mysql-client-core-5.6 mysql-server-5.6
  mysql-server-core-5.6
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libmecab2 libmysqlclient20 mysql-client mysql-community-client
  mysql-community-server mysql-server
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libmysqlclient-dev mysql-common
2 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 4 to remove and 293 not upgraded.
Need to get 34.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 83.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  mysql-common libmysqlclient20 libmysqlclient-dev mysql-community-client
  mysql-client mysql-community-server mysql-server
E: There were unauthenticated packages and -y was used without --allow-unauthenticated
apt-get.diagnostics
apt-get install failed
$ cat ${TRAVIS_HOME}/apt-get-update.log
Get:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu trusty InRelease [33.5 kB]
Get:2 http://dl.hhvm.com/ubuntu trusty InRelease [3,106 B]
Ign:3 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.4 InRelease
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Get:5 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt trusty-pgdg InRelease [61.4 kB]
Get:6 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.4 Release [2,495 B]
Ign:7 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Get:9 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.4 Release.gpg [801 B]
Get:10 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates InRelease [65.9 kB]
Get:12 http://dl.hhvm.com/ubuntu trusty/main amd64 Packages [1,807 B]
Get:13 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports InRelease [65.9 kB]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security InRelease [65.9 kB]
Get:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/redis-server/ubuntu trusty InRelease [15.4 kB]
Ign:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Get:8 http://dl.bintray.com/apache/cassandra 39x InRelease [3,168 B]
Get:16 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu trusty/mysql-5.7 amd64 Packages [3,361 B]
Get:17 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu trusty/mysql-5.7 i386 Packages [3,379 B]
Get:18 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty Release [58.5 kB]
Get:19 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu trusty InRelease [37.1 kB]
Get:20 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse amd64 Packages [13.6 kB]
Get:21 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty Release.gpg [933 B]
Get:22 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release [943 B]
Ign:11 http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu ./ InRelease
Get:23 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg [819 B]
Get:25 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt trusty-pgdg/main amd64 Packages [200 kB]
Get:24 http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu ./ Release [1,609 B]
Get:27 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates/main Sources [527 kB]
Get:26 http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu ./ Release.gpg [473 B]
Get:28 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt trusty-pgdg/main i386 Packages [199 kB]
Ign:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/couchdb/stable/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Get:31 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates/restricted Sources [6,449 B]
Get:33 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates/universe Sources [288 kB]
Get:34 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates/multiverse Sources [7,287 B]
Get:29 http://dl.bintray.com/apache/cassandra 39x/main amd64 Packages [682 B]
Get:35 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,421 kB]
Get:32 http://dl.bintray.com/apache/cassandra 39x/main i386 Packages [682 B]
Get:36 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu trusty InRelease [20.8 kB]
Get:37 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu trusty/stable amd64 Packages [5,207 B]
Get:38 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [1,328 kB]
Get:39 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu trusty/edge amd64 Packages [6,366 B]
Get:40 https://packagecloud.io/computology/apt-backport/ubuntu trusty InRelease [23.5 kB]
Get:41 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates/main Translation-en [682 kB]
Get:42 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [21.4 kB]
Get:43 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [21.1 kB]
Get:44 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en [3,704 B]
Get:45 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [660 kB]
Get:46 https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/ubuntu trusty InRelease [23.2 kB]
Get:47 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [641 kB]
Get:48 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu trusty InRelease [15.4 kB]
Get:49 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages [1,110 B]
Get:50 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates/universe Translation-en [342 kB]
Get:51 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [16.0 kB]
Get:52 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [16.5 kB]
Get:53 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en [7,680 B]
Get:54 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security/main Sources [216 kB]
Get:56 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports/main Sources [10.4 kB]
Get:57 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports/restricted Sources [40 B]
Get:55 http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu ./ Packages [636 B]
Get:58 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports/universe Sources [41.3 kB]
Get:59 https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/ubuntu trusty InRelease [23.7 kB]
Get:60 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pollinate/ppa/ubuntu trusty InRelease [15.4 kB]
Get:61 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports/multiverse Sources [1,747 B]
Ign:46 https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Get:62 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages [14.7 kB]
Get:63 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports/main i386 Packages [14.7 kB]
Get:64 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports/main Translation-en [7,426 B]
Get:65 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages [40 B]
Get:66 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security/restricted Sources [5,050 B]
Get:67 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages [40 B]
Get:68 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en [40 B]
Get:69 https://packagecloud.io/computology/apt-backport/ubuntu trusty/main Sources [843 B]
Get:70 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages [52.5 kB]
Get:71 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security/universe Sources [125 kB]
Get:72 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages [52.4 kB]
Get:73 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports/universe Translation-en [40.0 kB]
Get:74 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty InRelease [15.5 kB]
Get:75 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages [1,392 B]
Get:76 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages [1,376 B]
Get:77 https://packagecloud.io/computology/apt-backport/ubuntu trusty/main amd64 Packages [3,628 B]
Get:78 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en [1,165 B]
Get:79 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security/multiverse Sources [3,068 B]
Get:80 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/main Sources [1,335 kB]
Get:81 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/restricted Sources [5,335 B]
Get:82 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security/main amd64 Packages [1,000 kB]
Get:83 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/universe Sources [7,926 kB]
Get:84 https://packagecloud.io/computology/apt-backport/ubuntu trusty/main i386 Packages [848 B]
Get:85 http://ppa.launchpad.net/couchdb/stable/ubuntu trusty Release [15.1 kB]
Get:86 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/multiverse Sources [211 kB]
Get:87 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/main amd64 Packages [1,743 kB]
Get:88 https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/ubuntu trusty/main Sources [20 B]
Get:89 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/main i386 Packages [1,739 kB]
Get:90 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security/main i386 Packages [912 kB]
Get:91 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/restricted amd64 Packages [16.0 kB]
Get:92 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/restricted i386 Packages [16.4 kB]
Get:93 https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/ubuntu trusty/main amd64 Packages [7,433 B]
Get:94 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/universe amd64 Packages [7,589 kB]
Get:95 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security/main Translation-en [525 kB]
Get:96 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages [18.1 kB]
Get:97 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/universe i386 Packages [7,597 kB]
Get:98 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages [17.8 kB]
Get:99 https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/ubuntu trusty/main i386 Packages [7,192 B]
Get:100 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security/restricted Translation-en [3,272 B]
Get:101 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages [169 kB]
Get:102 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages [368 kB]
Get:103 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/multiverse i386 Packages [172 kB]
Get:104 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security/universe i386 Packages [350 kB]
Get:105 https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/ubuntu trusty/main Sources [20 B]
Get:106 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security/universe Translation-en [199 kB]
Get:107 https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/ubuntu trusty/main amd64 Packages [7,165 B]
Get:108 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [4,723 B]
Get:109 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages [4,876 B]
Get:110 https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/ubuntu trusty/main i386 Packages [7,165 B]
Get:111 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en [2,426 B]
Get:112 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/redis-server/ubuntu trusty/main amd64 Packages [1,844 B]
Get:113 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/redis-server/ubuntu trusty/main i386 Packages [1,844 B]
Get:114 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/redis-server/ubuntu trusty/main Translation-en [990 B]
Get:115 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu trusty/main amd64 Packages [3,486 B]
Get:116 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu trusty/main i386 Packages [3,484 B]
Get:117 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu trusty/main Translation-en [2,332 B]
Get:118 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu trusty/main amd64 Packages [7,571 B]
Get:119 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu trusty/main i386 Packages [7,700 B]
Get:120 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu trusty/main Translation-en [2,388 B]
Get:121 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pollinate/ppa/ubuntu trusty/main amd64 Packages [430 B]
Get:122 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pollinate/ppa/ubuntu trusty/main i386 Packages [430 B]
Get:123 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pollinate/ppa/ubuntu trusty/main Translation-en [374 B]
Get:124 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty/main amd64 Packages [1,553 B]
Get:125 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty/main i386 Packages [1,553 B]
Get:126 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty/main Translation-en [834 B]
Get:127 http://ppa.launchpad.net/couchdb/stable/ubuntu trusty Release.gpg [316 B]
Get:128 http://ppa.launchpad.net/couchdb/stable/ubuntu trusty/main amd64 Packages [985 B]
Get:129 http://ppa.launchpad.net/couchdb/stable/ubuntu trusty/main i386 Packages [985 B]
Get:130 http://ppa.launchpad.net/couchdb/stable/ubuntu trusty/main Translation-en [644 B]
Fetched 39.6 MB in 8s (4,535 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
W: GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu trusty InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1550412832  KEYEXPIRED 1550412832  KEYEXPIRED 1550412832
W: The repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu trusty InRelease' is not signed.
W: GPG error: https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/ubuntu trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6B05F25D762E3157
W: The repository 'https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/ubuntu trusty InRelease' is not signed.
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
6B05F25D762E3157  
W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/couchdb/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg: Signature by key 15866BAFD9BCC4F3C1E0DFC7D69548E1C17EAB57 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
The command "sudo -E apt-get -yq --no-install-suggests --no-install-recommends $(travis_apt_get_options) install mysql-server mysql-client" failed and exited with 100 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```

I'm not trying to install my own packages from apt-get. And problem just appears and disappears few times per month

Comment: What do the surrounding commands look like? Which distro, which repo, what exactly do the diagnostics from `apt-get` say?

Comment: have added my travis.yaml

Comment: And the `apt-get` output leading up to the final error message?

Comment: have added output

Comment: And now you cannot understand the error message? `E: There were unauthenticated packages and -y was used without --allow-unauthenticated`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Travis Can't Find Debian Package in Custom Source Repo, Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44807022/travis-cant-find-debian-package-in-custom-source-repo-why)

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the following error on Debian 9.4 stretch when I tried to install the older installer , mysql-apt-config_0.8.6-1_all.deb

W: GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian stretch InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 8C718D3B5072E1F5 MySQL Release Engineering  
E: The repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian stretch InRelease' is not signed. 
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

However I used apt-get and gdebi-core to get mysql installed and not mariadb. Im guessing the process will be similar to Ubuntu. If youre willing to go outside the script, the following might help.

This will get you the latest mysql package with latest signing key as of 2019. If you find the signature is invalid or expired,  you get can always get the latest installer from here https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ )

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.12-1_all.deb

apt-get install gdebi-core

gdebi mysql-apt-config_0.8.12-1_all.deb
```

****************************** in the wizard  **************************************************

Configuring mysql-apt-config

Which MySQL product do you wish to configure?

select MySQL Server & Cluster (Currently selected: mysql-5.7) 
tab
select ok

then tab to ok and hit enter

Configuring mysql-apt-config

Which server version do you wish to receive?

select mysql 5.7

then tab to ok and hit enter

---

You can always review your selection manual by editing /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list sources list directly.
Install MySQL Server

```
apt update

apt install mysql-server

systemctl status mysql
```

should show something similar

systemctl status mysql
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-02-24 08:57:51 UTC; 10min ago
 Main PID: 14787 (mysqld)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─14787 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

Feb 24 08:57:51 test.com systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Feb 24 08:57:51 test.com systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.

This should fix your mysql installation.

Answer (score 0):

**Error: W: GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu xenial InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1550412832  KEYEXPIRED 1550412832  KEYEXPIRED 1550412832**

W: The repository ‘https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu xenial InRelease’ is not signed.

**Solution:**

Use below command to check expired key lists,

**$ sudo apt-key list | grep -A 1 expired**

**Output:**

pub   1024D/5072E1F5 2003-02-03 [expired: 2019-02-17]

uid                  MySQL Release Engineering

To Renew the expired key,

**$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 5072E1F5**

**Output:**

Executing: /tmp/tmp.XwFcFWU4xU/gpg.1.sh --keyserver

keys.gnupg.net

--recv-keys

5072E1F5

gpg: requesting key 5072E1F5 from hkp server keys.gnupg.net

gpg: key 5072E1F5: "MySQL Release Engineering " 28 new signatures

gpg: Total number processed: 1

gpg:         new signatures: 28

Update the System repositories.

**$ sudo apt-get update**